# android emulator runs from android studio but not from command line

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am running MacOS with 64GB RAM. I have multiple AVDs on this machine, all of them can be run via the emulator in Android Studio.  However, none of them will boot from command line.

All AVDs give the same behavior: The device appears on screen, but no boot/loading information ever appears on the virtual device screen.  It just remains black forever (I waited hours).  In the emulator log, I see an endless stream of messages like

[CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] returning nil because device is nil

I have tried various command line options for the emulator, like various memory sizes, gpu options, turning off cameras, etc.  Everything gives the same behavior.

I have ensured my Android Studio version is up to date.

How can I resolve this issue?